# String Formatting/Template/Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, formatting

I have a string format let's say  where A = alphanumeric and N = Integer so the template is "AAAAAA-NNNN" now the user sometimes will ommit the dash, and sometimes the "NNNN" is only three digits in which case I need it to pad a 0. The first digit of "NNNN" has to be 0, thus if it is a number is is the last digit of the "AAAAAA" as opposed to the first digit of "NNNN". So in essence if I have the following inputs I want the following results:

**Sample Inputs:**

```
"SAMPLE0001"
"SAMPL1-0002"
"SAMPL3003"
"SAMPLE-004"
```

**Desired Outputs:**

```
"SAMPLE-0001"
"SAMPL1-0002"
"SAMPL3-0003"
"SAMPLE-0004"
```

I know how to check for this using regular expressions but essentially I want to do the opposite.  I was wondering if there is a easy way to do this other than doing a nested conditional checking for all these variations.  I am using python and pandas but either will suffice.

The regex pattern would be:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]-\d\d\d\d"
```

or in abbreviated form:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}-[\d]{4}"
```

Comment: FYI... you can simplify that regex at the bottom like this `[a-zA-Z]{6}-[\d]{4}`

Comment: how the above regex would convert `SAMPLE003` to `SAMPLE-0003` ?

Comment: it wouldn't, that's the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: @aensm it won't match the second case.

Comment: thanks aensm for the abbreviated syntax

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm not try to solve the problem, just point out that the example regex could be more concise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible through two `re.sub` functions.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''SAMPLE0001
SAMPL1-0002
SAMPL3003
SAMPLE-004'''
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?m)(?<=-)(?=\d{3}$)', '0', re.sub(r'(?m)(?<=^[A-Z\d]{6})(?!-)', '-', s)))
SAMPLE-0001
SAMPL1-0002
SAMPL3-0003
SAMPLE-0004
```

Explanation:

- `re.sub(r'(?m)(?<=^[A-Z\d]{6})(?!-)', '-', s)` would be processed at first. It just places a hyphen after the 6th character from the beginning only if the following character is not a hyphen.
- `re.sub(r'(?m)(?<=-)(?=\d{3}$)', '0', re.sub(r'(?m)(?<=^[A-Z\d]{6})(?!-)', '-', s))` By taking the above command's output as input, this would add a digit `0` after to the hyphen and the characters following must be exactly 3.

Comment: what are you the regex king?  SO is making me wait another minute to accept the answer!

Comment: now I just need to figure out what this all means :) but it works!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, it uses [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
import re
inputs = ['SAMPLE0001', 'SAMPL1-0002', 'SAMPL3003','SAMPLE-004']
outputs = []
for input_ in inputs:
    m = re.match(r'(\w{6})-?\d?(\d{3})', input_)
    outputs.append('-0'.join(m.groups()))
print(outputs)
# ['SAMPLE-0001', 'SAMPL1-0002', 'SAMPL3-0003', 'SAMPLE-0004']
```

We are matching the regex `(\w{6})-?\d?(\d{3})` against the input strings and joining the captured groups with the string `'-0'`. This is very simple and fast.

Let me know if you need a more in-depth explanation of the regex itself.